# Dumping plugin memory of a browser

Tags: reverse-engineering

How can I dump a memory of a plugin running inside a browser. For example, I want to analyze the memory of acrobat reader which is running inside chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The methods vary widely between operating systems. Mind to be a bit more to the point with details? Windows? Linux? MacOSX? ... something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in case of most common browsers plugins are dynamic librarys loaded into the process of the browser. So you need to attach to that process with a debugger and then go to the module that is the plugin.

For chrome and pdf reader:
Chrome spawns a new process for almost everything, so first you need to load up any pdf in the browser so the plugin gets loaded. Then you can find the matching PID for that tab via the integrated taskmanager from chrome. When you attach to this process with a debugger, you should see the module "pdf", which is a dll located in the chrome installation directory and I believe is a modified version of acrobat reader.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by memory dump, and what exactly you're looking to do with it. There are tools such as [Memoryze](http://www.mandiant.com/resources/download/memoryze) that you can dump the memory of a running process. I've used it forensically but I've never tried to take said dump and throw it in IDA.

You could also attach a debugger and get at memory that way. It all depends what you're trying to analyze/reverse.